# Can we make the illumination on a bulb higher than the other when two are in series

Tags: mains

I have a question:
If suppose we have two identical bulbs connected in series with a supply source. Is there any way to illuminate one of the bulbs brighter than the other through any means, except an external power input, and without disturbing the other bulb.

**UPDATE:** 
Here's what I am trying to solve, which is quite related with my above question.

I was testing a 310V DC to 220V/160V AC inverter circuit. I plugged it with my home 220V AC socket which had a 200 watt/220V bulb in series with one of its lines.

I also had another 200 watt/220V bulb attached with the secondary of the inverter.

When switched ON I found the 200 watt connected with the inverter glowing 5 times brighter than the series 200 watt connected with the AC mains line.

Technically both the bulbs are in series because the inverter is in series with the 200 watt mains series bulb. Therefore both should have had similar glow?

I am trying to solve this puzzle.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: put a resistor in parallel across bulb 2.

Comment: You'd never put light bulbs in series in a mains installation, unless they are meant to be identical and driven by half the mains voltage. This thus sounds extremely much like badly represented homework...

Comment: @solar Mike. That's indeed a very simple solution, very silly of me...thanks very much for your reply!

Comment: @Marcus, I am trying to solve a related overunity puzzle experienced in one of my experiments, and that's why I put this question to get a clarification!

Comment: Why have you got a bulb in series with the mains input? You say you have a bulb in series with the output. This implies it is in series with some other device. Due to the possible confusion with your terminology we need a schematic to be clear. "*Technically both the bulbs are in series because the inverter is in series with the 200 watt mains series bulb.*" No. In series has a particular meaning in electrical circuits. It means that they are directly connected and share a common node in the circuit.

Comment: What voltage are the bulbs designed to work on?

Comment: @HandyHowie they are both 220V/200 watt rated, I had one bulb in series with mains just to safeguard my home wiring in case something went wrong.

Comment: The bulbs are "exactly similar"? That's an oxymoron.

Comment: Have you tested the voltages across each bulb?

Comment: The series bulb is fixed in a top holder of my home wiring so it was difficult to check the VA across it. The illumination is a direct indication of the power in the bulbs which look unusual, so my only question is, is it something mysterious going on, or an ordinary scientific principle that I am unable to understand.

Comment: The resistance of a filament bulb increases with temperature.  The one that is dim will not have 220V across it and it’s resistance will be lower than the bright one.  This is probably the reason for your observation.

Comment: So how's the inverter bulb getting hotter than the series bulb? All the power coming to the inverter bulb has to enter through the series bulb, making it equally hotter?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f413T5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. When SW1 is closed BULB2 will glow brighter and BULB1 will dim.*

R1 will have to be rated for the voltage, current and power it will be subject to. SW1 is, of course, optional.

---

Update after comments:

> While testing a 330V DC invrter I plugged it with my mains 220V input to get rectified 300V for the inverter. The mians input had a 200 watt bulb in series, and the inverter output also had a 200 watt bulb in series...the inverter bulb illuminated much brighter than the series 200 watt bulb, I am trying to solve how this is happening.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuleYI.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Test circuit showing series connected lamp on input for current limiting and test lamp on output. Infeed lamp's estimated power output is 5 W and output lamp output is 40 W.*

The test load is wired in parallel to (or across) the inverter output.

By measuring the actual RMS voltage and current into the inverter and out of the inverter you will be able to work out the VA in and VA out. If these are done correctly you will find that the input power is somewhat greater than the output power due to losses in the inverter.

The bulbs are not in series because there is a voltage converter in between them and they are running on different currents.

> A series circuit is a closed circuit in which the current follows one path, as opposed to a parallel circuit where the circuit is divided into two or more paths. In a series circuit, the current through each load is the same and the total voltage across the circuit is the sum of the voltages across each load. Source: [Chegg.com](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/series-circuit-4).

In your case there are alternate paths to N through the inverter circuitry so it fails the definition of "series".

Comment: Now that is showing the options possible, plus 1.

Comment: oops, then I think my question is not solved yet? referring to the above figure I thought R1 would develop a higher voltage across itself causing lamp1 to glow brighter, but if it's lamp2 then I am afraid my puzzle still remains unsolved...

Comment: The bulb which is being modified has to glow brighter, is there any way to do it??

Comment: Why can you not move R1 in parallel with LAMP2?

Comment: @Transistor, while testing a 330V DC invrter I plugged it with my mains 220V input to get rectified 300V for the inverter. The mians input had a 200 watt bulb in series, and the inverter output also had a 200 watt bulb in series...the inverter bulb illuminated much brighter than the series 200 watt bulb, I am trying to solve how this is happening.

Comment: This is a very different situation than that you described in your question and that information should have been in the question along with what you are trying to achieve. The two bulbs are on different circuits. Please edit your question and add a schematic and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Please give me sometime I'll modify the question...thank you!

Comment: OK I have updated the question, I hope I have done it correctly!

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar correctly would have meant you including a diagram...

Comment: The tried to draw it circuitlab but while saving it realized it's a premium service and I need to pay for it, so I couldn't proceed. By the way here's the image I am trying to solve: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/free-en-from-inv.png

Comment: As explained in my comment, when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you don't need an account. Use the "Save and Insert" button. Surely you have a proper circuit schematic and not a cartoon?!

Comment: The image I have shown is not a "cartoon", if you have the willingness to solve the issue then it's fine, otherwise you can delete this conversation.

Comment: @Transistor, my only question is, is it normal or a feasible thing to see the inverter bulb showing much higher glow than the series bulb as per the second schematic you have presented above? I have even tried swapping the bulbs and the results were unchanged.

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar you should read or **re-read** the answer provided as it explains the situation, including the meaning of « series » which you have incorrect.